# How do you debug properly in visual studio while using WatiN framework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, watin

I have being trying to debug my program which is around couple of hundreds lines of code, I have been trying hard to debug the program properly,
each and every control of the program leaves blocks, starts from different point whenever I press f11 to see each and every step of my code,

Is there is any better approach to do debugging properly by using some other tools.

Comment: You know you can step out, and step over code right ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek13f001.aspx / http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MasteringInDebugging.aspx

Comment: I know the basics what you have mentioned in this article, when you watin, f11 is not working properly, it suddenly jumps to another statement from nowhere when i perform buttonclick function

Answer (score 0):

You can get VS to stop when exceptions are thrown - Debug -> Exceptions. Then tick 'Thrown' for CLR Exceptions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx

You can also put Breakpoints against lines in code. Just click in the left margin or go to Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints.

Comment: though it was a nice suggestion it wont help help me, it was very hard to use breakpoints, watches, in Watin framework..my question is there is any other best tool  to do debugging in a nice and efficient way...

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this series of articles about debugging:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2009/02/08/the-art-of-debugging-a-developer-s-best-friend-intro-lesson-1.aspx
But there is a lot more turorials on the net. It is worth researching. When I started programming, I learned that knowing your debugger well can save a lot of time :)

Comment: thanks for this article, it was quite interesting, can you be more specific, if i work in watin environment.....

Comment: i did some research. watin test recorder looks like promissing tool http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/ it supports breakpoints. Never used it, though